# Importing Firebase_Messaging makes build fail

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I import firebase_messaging into my app(in pubspec.yaml and an import statement). My app fails to build. It was working perfectly before trying to import firebase_messaging. I checked the flutter directory to make sure it was the right version and everything. I'm kind of at a loss here.

I tried updating android, and flutter.

Pubspec.yaml

```
     dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6
  firebase_analytics: ^3.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.5+1

  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+6
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.2
  rxdart: ^0.22.0
  css_colors: ^1.0.2
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.5.0
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.2
```

This is the error message

```
     Could not determine the dependencies of task 
':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[18.0.
  0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[18.0.0], but fire
 base-iid version was 19.0.0.

 The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
 ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- messaging@18.0.0
 -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_messaging' which depends onto 
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@18.0.
  0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@17.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_core' which depends onto 
com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.9
     -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- 
   analytics@17.0.0
      -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_analytics' which depends 
    onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@16.5.
  0
      -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
   measurement-api@17.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@19.0.0

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with 
./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google- 
   services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding 
"googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
   uild.gradle file.

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


 BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after doing a bit more research I found out an answer. 
I added
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
to my app level gradle file and I get some warnings, but the app itself builds and runs.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy. How have more people not run into this issue? I followed the documentation exactly, and this was definitely not in it. If anyone knows I would love to know, I'm pretty clueless with this stuff still.